# One dimensional subspaces of a 3 dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, multiple choice

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a 3-dimentional vector space over the field $F_3=\Bbb Z/3 \Bbb Z$  of $3$ elements.the number of distinct 1 dimentional subspaces of $V$ is

> 1. $13$
> 2. $26$
> 3. $9$
> 4. $15$

Answer (score 9):

Hint:

If $V_n(q)$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ on a field $F=GF(q)$, the number of all one-dimensional subspace of $V$ will be: $$\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$$ In fact, all non zero scalar products of $\langle e\rangle\subset V$ generate the same subspaces of dimension one.

Comment: where can I get the proof of this result?

Comment: @kinkar: Let $\langle e\rangle\subset V$. So it has a form like $\langle e\rangle=\{\alpha e\mid \alpha\in F\}$. We have a total number of $q^n-1$ of such these subspaces. But all scalar products of $e$ make similar subspaces. So, we should eliminate them by that dividing.

Comment: $+\left(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x\right)\;\;\ddot\smile$

Comment: @kinkar Check it out [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteField.html)